# How to sort a 2 dimentional array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, sorting

I know this may be answered a million times, but i can't quite find what i wanna do in my case.

I have an array as following:

```
tag_array = [[tag1, tag_count1], [tag1, tag_count2], [tag3, tag_count3], [tag4, tag_count4]]
```

And i want to sort it alphabetically according to tag1, tag2, tag3...

I have tried the following:

```
tag_array.sort {|a,b| a[0] <=> b[0]}
```

but without luck !

Am i missing something here ?

Thanks!

PS: tag1, tag2, tag3... are strings.

Answer (score 5):

[`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) comes to the rescue:

```
tag_array.sort_by { |el| el.first }
```

The above might be written in short notation (credits to @justin-licata):

```
tag_array.sort_by &:first
```

BTW, `sort_by` is proven to be much more efficient that `sort`.

Comment: Or to shorthand it a bit, `tag_array.sort_by(&:first)`. plus 1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `tag_array.sort`

You don't need to worry about adding your own block, assuming you're just doing [String, Integer] array pairs within an array (which you are). Sort handles that for you as arrays are compared in an element-wise manner (thanks mudasobwa for this added clarity).

Comment: _Assuming you are doing `Array`s_ actually. Arrays are compared in element-wise mnnner, that’s why it works.

Answer (score 0):

If u say

```
arr2 = arr.sort {|a,b| a[0] <=> b[0]}
```

or

```
arr2 = arr.sort_by{|x,y|x}
```

it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

```
2.2.0 :007 > tag_array = [['tag1', 3], ['tag2', 2], ['tag3', 23], ['tag4', 44]]
 => [["tag1", 3], ["tag2", 2], ["tag3", 23], ["tag4", 44]] 
2.2.0 :008 > tag_array.sort_by{|tag| [tag[1], tag[0]]}
 => [["tag2", 2], ["tag1", 3], ["tag3", 23], ["tag4", 44]] 
2.2.0 :009 > tag_array.sort_by{|tag| [tag[0], tag[1]]}
 => [["tag1", 3], ["tag2", 2], ["tag3", 23], ["tag4", 44]]
```